# seperate 2 javascript file in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pageload

i having a very weird problem now . I has separate 2 jquery js file with my aspx file.However the pageload doesn't seem like work. 
Because I'm using UpdatePanel to asynchronously call a button click event in a page. 
Therefore i attach my click event within the page load method

Here is the screen shoot of my js file

[image]

Here is the sample code for **modalPopup.js**

```
function pageLoad() {

//#region Search function   
$("[id$=txtSearch]").keyup(function (e) {
    "[id$=txtCurrentPage2]"
    $("[id$=txtCurrentPage2]").val(1)
    $("[id$=txtCurrentPage]").val(1)
    $("[id$=hfCurrentTxt]").val(1)
    var txtSearch = $("[id$=txtSearch]").val()
    var pagesize = $("[id$=ddlRowPerPage]").val()
    var skip = $("[id$=txtCurrentPage2]").val()
    var type = $("[id$=hfGvType]").val()
    sendData(txtSearch, skip, pagesize, type);
    e.preventDefault();
});
//#endregion
```

The sample code for the **ASPX.js**

```
function pageLoad() {
$("[id$=txtCMemberID]").bind('keyup change', function (e) {
    alert("hello");
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

}

The modalPopup.js can work very smoothly, but the ASPX.js seem like doesn't work.Anyone face this problem before.? Please guide me some idea. Thanks

Comment: you are ruining both as one function with same name  which might cause you an error why not put it all in one function

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Because modalPopup.js may has hundread line of code. Therefore i separate 2 js file which easy for me to easy managed code.Do you has any solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand, I'd wager that you are loading ASPX.js first, and then loading modalPopup.js later in the page. Both files define a global function named `pageLoad`. As you cannot have two separate global functions that share the same name, one is redefining the other. Rename one of the functions (it doesn't have to be called `pageLoad`). Example as follows:

Change ASPX.js to:

```
function bindKeyUpChangeHandler() {
    $("[id$=txtCMemberID]").bind('keyup change', function (e) {
        alert("hello");
        e.preventDefault();

    });
}
```

then call `bindKeyUpChangeHandler()` in addition to `pageLoad()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Because **modalPopup.js** may has hundread line of code. Therefore i separate 2 js file which easy for me to easy managed code.Do you has any solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring like that why not use

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {


 //do stuff on page load

});
```